# qTip2 adjust image size to fit window

Tags: jquery, image-resizing, qtip2, window-resize

I want my qTip to display a larger image of the clicked thumbnail in the center of the screen, but to adjust the size of the tooltip and image depending on the window size.

So far my results only display the tooltip at a default width, and doesn't adjust to display the full image.

http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/5206/

```
// Create the tooltips only on document load
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        // Grab fullsize image src
        var bigSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace(".jpg", "_b.jpg");
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                title: '<img src="' + bigSrc + '" alt="" />',
                text: function(api) {
                    // Retrieve content from ALT attribute of the $('.selector') element
                    return $(this).attr('alt');
                }
            },
        position: {
            my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
            target: $(window)
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            modal: true
        },
        hide: false,
        style: {
            tip: false,
            classes: 'preview'
            }
        });
    });
});​
```